# Failed to resolve module 'C:\Users\***\Desktop\Bot\modules\data\MongoDB.js': ExpectedValidationError > s.instance(V)

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose, discord.js

I'm attempting to setup a MongoDB connection, but I'm running into an error when launching my bot.

`Failed to resolve module 'C:\Users\luci\Desktop\Lunar Bot\modules\data\MongoDB.js': ExpectedValidationError > s.instance(V)`

The bot is being developed in TypeScript and is being converted into JS on load.

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export class MongoConnection {
  public versions = "^7";
  public mongoose!: typeof mongoose;

  async onstart() {
    this.mongoose = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB!);

    if (this.mongoose) console.log("Connected to MongoDB Database");

    return true;
  }
}

export default new MongoConnection();
```

Converted JS Code:

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
export class MongoConnection {
    constructor() {
        this.versions = "^7";
    }
    async onstart() {
        this.mongoose = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB);
        if (this.mongoose)
            console.log("Connected to MongoDB Database");
        return true;
    }
}
export default new MongoConnection();
//# sourceMappingURL=MongoDB.js.map
```

Any idea as to why I'm having an error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The issue was the `async onstart()`. It's supposed to be `async onStart()`.

I was typing just a tad too fast and didn't capitalize the S..